# knn prediction for a specific value of x

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, knn, predict

I am trying to figure out how to apply `knn.reg` function to predict y (which in this case is the `mpg` of the `Auto` dataset) for a specific value of x (it's the 'horsepower' variable of the same dataset).

At first, I used a `knn.reg` function to build a knn regression model with k=10, which looks like this:

```
#Preliminary setup
library(ISLR)
library(fastDummies)
library(leaps)
library(boot)
library(FNN)
library(caTools)

df<-Auto
df$origin <- as.factor(df$origin)
df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "origin")
df <- df[,!(names(df) %in% c("name", "origin","origin_1"))]

#Attempted models    
knn.model<-knn.reg(train=df$horsepower, y=df$mpg, k=10)

split<-sample.split(df$mpg, SplitRatio=0.8)
train=df[split,]
test=df[!split,]

knn.model<-knn.reg(train=train[c('horsepower')], test=test[c('horsepower')], y=df$mpg, k=10)
```

I've tried two models that either include or exclude test data that
is split from the original data, but I think I would like to use the
entire dataset as the training data.

After constructing these models, **I tried to use predict() function to estimate the mpg of a vehicle when its horsepower is 200,** which would look something like this:

```
mpg<-c(200)
predict(knn.model, newdata=mpg)
```

Problem with `predict()` function, however, was that it gave out an error telling me that `predict() can't be applied to class "knnRegCV."`

I am unsure if I should use a function other than `predict()`, or if the code I have is missing something essential. I'd appreciate any suggestions or comments that can help me address this issue. Massive thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `predict()` does not have a method for the object that the `knn.reg()` function returns, but you can easily use the `test=` argument. Using your first `knn.model`:

```
knn.reg(train=df$horsepower, test=200, y=df$mpg, k=10)
# Prediction:
# [1] 12.45
```

Since you have only one predictor, you need to create a data frame to estimate more then one value:

```
pred <- data.frame(horsepower=c(100, 150, 200, 250))   
knn.reg(train=df$horsepower, test=pred, y=df$mpg, k=10)
# Prediction:
# [1] 17.90 14.50 12.45 12.90
```

Comment: You are truly amazing, always find fascinating that the answer I've been contemplating for hours is that simple. Massive thanks.